# $Hom_\mathbb Z$ and direct products

Tags: homological-algebra

This is problem 2.25(ii) from Rotman's Homological Algebra Text.

### 1. Problem

Let $p$ be a prime, $B_n$ be a cycle group of order $p^n$, and $A = \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty B_n$. Show that
$$ \mathcal S := Hom_\mathbb Z(A, A) \ncong \bigoplus Hom_\mathbb Z(A, B_n) =: \mathcal T $$

Hint: $\mathcal S$ has an element of infinite order while $\mathcal T$ has elements of only finite order.

### 2. Partial Proof

For $\mathcal S$, note that $1_A$ has the desired property because for each $n \in \mathbb N$ there exists an $a \in A$ such that $p^n 1_A(a) = p^n a \ne 0$.

### Update

See my attempted answer.

Comment: Re question 1, "finite order" is meant with respect to pointwise addition, that is, the group operation $(f,g)\mapsto f+g$ given by $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$.

Comment: @DavidMoews: Under your definition, wouldn't both sets have elements order $\le p^n$? Both images are contained in $A=\bigoplus B$, whose elements have order that divides $p^n$.

Comment: Keep in mind that you are taking a sum over $n$.

Comment: I still don't see it. Let $(k_i b) \in A$. Then $p^n (k_i b) = (p^n k_i b) = 0$. What am I missing?

Comment: You are not using one single $n$!  You are taking a sum over $n$.  Outside a specific summand of $A$ or a specific $B_n$, there is no "$p^n$".

Comment: Ah hah! You're perhaps looking at the text itself, because I didn't even use $B_n$ here. Thanks! Will think on this a bit.

Comment: $A$ is a direct sum, for each $(b_i) \ \in A$ there exists a $N$ such that $b_n = 0$ for each $n \ge N$. Then $p^N(b_i) = 0$.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  So, every element of $A$ has finite order.

Comment: That's bad! I need to show there's an element in $\mathcal S$ that has infinite order, but  the image of every element is contained in $A$ which has only finite order elements..

Comment: Fortunately, $\cal S$ and $A$ are not the same, so it's possible for $\cal S$ to have an element of infinite order although $A$ does not.

Comment: Under your definition of order, it seems like you're saying $f^2(x) = f(x) + f(x)$. Then $f^{p^N}(x) = 0$ for each $x \in A$. I must be misunderstanding what order means.

Comment: For $p^n f\in{\cal S}$ to vanish, there must be some fixed $n$ such that $p^nf(x)=0$ for all $x$.  Otherwise, if $n$ is not fixed, even writing down the expression "$p^n f$" makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathcal S$, note that $1_A$ has the desired property because for each $n \in \mathbb N$ there exists an $a \in A$ such that $(1_A)(a)$ has order greater than $p^n$. For example, $a = (0, \cdots, b_{n+1}, 0, \cdots )$. Hence, $\mathcal S$ has an element of infinite order.

Let $(f_i) \in \mathcal T$ Because $(f_i)$ is a direct sum, there exists a $N$ such that $f_n = 0$ for all $n \ge N$. But then $(f_i)^{p^N} = 0$. So $\mathcal T$ has all elements of finite order.

Comment: OK, although to completely prove that $1_A$ has infinite order, you need to also look at the possibility that it has a finite order which is not a power of $p$.

Comment: Done. Thanks again for your patient help!